# Width of Line Renderer in inspector zero after setting startWidth and endWidth in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created an empty game object and attached a line renderer component to it in the inspector and also set it's position size array to 2. The rest of the stuff was done in the following script for animating a line. When I run the code the values of the positions change whiles the width is always zero (my observation from the inspector), so the line does not appear. What's causing this and how can I solve it?

```
public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour {

private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
private float counter;
private float dist;

public float lineDrawSpeed;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer> ();
lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.25f;
lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.25f;
lineRenderer.SetPosition (0, new Vector3 (0, 0, 0));

dist = Vector3.Distance (new Vector3 (0, 0, 0), new Vector3 (1.5f, 0, 0));

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

if (counter < dist) {
    counter += 0.1f / lineDrawSpeed;
    float x = Mathf.Lerp (0, dist, counter);

    Vector3 pointA = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
    Vector3 pointB = new Vector3 (1.5f, 0, 0);

    Vector3 pointAlongLine = x * Vector3.Normalize (pointB - pointA) + pointA;
    lineRenderer.SetPosition (1, pointAlongLine);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your `float x = Mathf.Lerp (0, dist, counter);` is ever 0 because if yes then `Vector3 pointAlongLine` wil be 0 also so you will draw line from 0 to 0.

Next check your `LineRenderer.widthMultiplier` if it's 0 your line won't be drawn also.

Also I gave a try to your code and this is the result:
[image: line.png]

So I'd like you to explain more what do you want to acheive.